# WAF FILE could not EXPORT due to no WEB PROJECT option found

Tags: java, spring-boot, war, spring-tool-suite, war-filedeployment

I was trying to create a war file on spring tool suite 4 (windows version). But as I was about to export the it to the local file system, I couldn't find the web project (wiseai-console) option of the project I want to export. There was another web project (wiseai-box) in the options, but it wasn't the one I want to export.

[web project options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jqWHD.png)

I tried configuring the project properties in project facets by adding dynamic web module, but it said I needed java 1.8 or newer. Then, I tried updating my java version and spring tool suite version, but it made no difference. I still couldn't add the dynamic web module. Who knows what I should do here to get the web project option?

[project facets, dynamic web module](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K03eI.png)

Comment: Don't. Use your build tool (maven or gradle) to create the proper war. Exporting it through your IDE won't work.